# What is this purple headdress that Tsukasa is commonly seen wearing?

Tags: fly-me-to-the-moon

In *Tonikaku Kawaii* (Fly Me to the Moon), the female lead character Tsukasa is usually seen wearing an oval-shaped purple headdress:

[image: Scene from Season 1 Episode 2. Tsukasa's back is turned to the camera and the viewer can see the oval-shaped purple headdress.]

What exactly is this accessory? I might have surmised that this is a type of [hairnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairnet), except that Tsukasa is seen wearing this headdress with her long hair let down. In fact, she takes off this headdress when she gets ready to sleep and ties her hair up into two side-buns:

[image: Scene from Season 1 Episode 2. Side-view of Tsukasa with her hair tied up into two buns. The purple headgear is clearly missing.]

Of course, I am not particularly knowledgeable about these kinds of accessories. Can someone enlighten me about what exactly Tsukasa is wearing?

Comment: The [wiki](https://tonikaku-kawaii.fandom.com/wiki/Tsukasa_Tsukuyomi) as well as [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/FlyMeToTheMoon) both refer to it as a hair clasp.

Comment: @Turamarth Hmmm. But then it looks like a hair clasp that clasps some hair underneath/behind the hair that she lets drop down? Seems unusual, at the very least.